# Next JS with Prisma - Update User Based Roles

Tags: reactjs, rest, next.js, prisma

I'm fairly new to both Next.js and Prisma. I'm working on an application to manage city councils, and so, the admin of this app can create users and roles and assign the roles to the users (that will be the city council employees).

Each user can receive multiple roles, and these roles can be updated, this is, the admin can remove or assign more roles to a user when he wants to.

In my database schema I have the table `Customer` (aka user because user is a reserved name in postgresql), the table `Role` and the table `Customer_role` that represents a relation n:m between the user and his roles.

What is the best way to update the user roles using prisma? Right now this is the way I'm doing it:

```js
const updateUser = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const {
    query: { id },
    body: { name, email, roles },
  } = req as { query: { [key: string]: string }; body: any };

  try {
    await prisma.customer.update({
      where: { id },
      data: { name, email },
    });
    await updateUserRoles(id, roles);
    const response = await prisma.customer.findUnique({
      where: { id: id },
      include: {
        customer_roles: {
          select: {
            role: {
              select: {
                id: true,
                name: true,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
    res.status(200).json(response);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json((error as Error).message);
  }
};

const updateUserRoles = async (userID: string, roles: { id: string }[]) => {
  try {
    await prisma.customer_role.deleteMany({
      where: {
        customer_id: userID,
      },
    });
    roles.map(async (role: { id: string }) => {
      await prisma.customer_role.create({
        data: {
          customer_id: userID,
          role_id: role.id,
        },
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

Initially I receive an array of roles that I want to assign to the user, but then when I want to updated them I delete all of the current user roles, and assign them again. This is generating a bug because the response object that should return the now updated user with his new roles is not waiting for the function `updateUserRoles`, and returns the user roles as an empty array. Only when I refresh the page and get the users again this bug is fixed. Here is my prisma schema as well as.

```js
model role {
  id                  String          @id @default(uuid())
  @db.Uuid
  name                String          @db.VarChar(255)
  polls               permission
  news                permission
  events              permission
  work_orders         permission
  pharmacies          permission
  points_of_interest  permission
  subscription_events permission
  customer_roles      customer_role[]
  created_at          DateTime        @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updated_at          DateTime?       @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)

  @@index([name], name: "idx_role_name")
}

model customer_role {
  id          String   @id @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid
  customer_id String   @db.Uuid
  role_id     String   @unique @db.Uuid
  customer    customer @relation(fields: [customer_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  role        role     @relation(fields: [role_id], references: [id])
}

model customer {
  id              String           @id @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid
  name            String           @db.VarChar(255)
  email           String           @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  external_uuid   String?          @unique @db.Uuid
  password        String?          @db.VarChar(255)
  created_at      DateTime         @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updated_at      DateTime?        @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  work_order_user work_order_user?
  customer_roles  customer_role[]

  @@index([name], name: "idx_customer_name")
  @@index([external_uuid], name: "idx_customer_external_uuid")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing updated roles is because you're using `async` inside the `map` under the `updateUserRoles` function. This will run asynchronously and you will not get the required response back as this would run in the background.

A better way to do this would be using [upsert](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#upsert):

```
const updateUserRoles = async (userID: string, roles: { id: string }[]) => {
  try {
    await prisma.$transaction(
    roles.map((role) =>
      prisma.customer_role.upsert({
        where: { id: role.id },
        create: { customer_id: userId, role_id: role.id },
        update: {},
      })
    )
  )
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```